# How to get the MTU size for an IP v4 packet in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, ipv4

How could I get the MTU size of Windows packets from a C++ program using Windows API?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing in general. It depends on the path to the target and on the NIC that is used to communicate via that path.

Comment: What is a Windows packet?

Comment: Ok, I am talking about the maximum size that can be used to send UDP datagrams from windows. In my tests I can send datagrams of ~65K. I got this size testing different values. So I am only asking about if there is a function (or something) to get this value. Thanks